# Java Nonogram (Checking Solutions) not working

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

Im making this nonogram and I got stuck at making the program check solutions (listener2). I hope you have eny idea of what is going on. I just started programming so be gentle.

main:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Start {
static String[] stolpci = new String[10];
static String[] vrstice = new String[10];
static JButton[][] gumbi = new JButton[11][11];
static JButton gumbResitev1 = new JButton("Pregled resitev");
static JButton gumbResitev2 = new JButton("Nova igra");
public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame okno = new JFrame("Nonogram");
    okno.setSize(1000, 1000);
    okno.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    okno.add(panel);

    JPanel polje = new JPanel(new GridLayout(11, 11));
    panel.add(polje, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JPanel nastavitve1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 1));
    panel.add(nastavitve1, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    nastavitve1.add(gumbResitev1);

    JPanel nastavitve2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 1));
    panel.add(nastavitve2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    nastavitve2.add(gumbResitev2);



    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++) {
            if (i < 1 || j < 1) {
                gumbi[i][j] = new JButton();
                gumbi[i][j].setBackground(Color.RED);
                polje.add(gumbi[i][j]);


            }

            else {

                gumbi[i][j] = new JButton();
                gumbi[i][j].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                gumbi[i][j].addActionListener(new Listener(gumbi));
                polje.add(gumbi[i][j]);

            }

        }
    }

    // matrika in resitve

    Random rand = new Random();
    int[][] poljeM = new int[10][10];
    for (int i = 0; i < poljeM.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < poljeM[i].length; j++) {
            poljeM[i][j] = rand.nextInt(2);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            System.out.print(poljeM[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
    }
    // stetje vrstic

    int crneV = 0;

    for (int g = 0; g < poljeM.length; g++) {
        crneV = 0;
        vrstice[g] = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < poljeM[0].length; i++) {
            if (poljeM[g][i] == 1) {
                crneV += 1;
            } else if (crneV != 0) {
                vrstice[g] += crneV + " ";
                crneV = 0;
            }

        }
        if (crneV != 0) {
            vrstice[g] += crneV + " ";
        }

    }

    // stetje stolpcev

    int crneS = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < poljeM[0].length; i++) {
        stolpci[i] = "";
        crneS = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < poljeM.length; j++) {
            if (poljeM[j][i] == 1) {
                crneS += 1;
            } else if (crneS != 0) {
                stolpci[i] += crneS + " ";
                crneS = 0;
            }
        }
        if (crneS != 0) {
            stolpci[i] += crneS + " ";
        }

    }

    for (int z = 1; z < 11; z++) {
        gumbi[0][z].setText(stolpci[z - 1]);
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
        gumbi[i][0].setText(vrstice[i - 1]);
    }


    gumbi[0][0].setText("Nonogram");

    // resize
            okno.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

listener1:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;

public class Listener implements ActionListener {
JButton[][] gumbi = Start.gumbi;

public Listener(JButton[][] gumbi) {
    this.gumbi = gumbi;

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    JButton gumb = (JButton) e.getSource();

    if (gumb.getBackground() == Color.WHITE) {
        gumb.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    } else if (gumb.getBackground() == Color.BLACK) {
        gumb.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }

}
}
```

listener2:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
public class Resitve extends Start implements ActionListener {
    JButton gumbResitev1 = Start.gumbResitev1;

    public Resitve (JButton gumbResitev1){
        this.gumbResitev1 = gumbResitev1;
    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton gumb = (JButton) e.getSource();

        String[] stetjeV = new String[10];
        int stevecC = 0;



        for (int i = 1; i < Start.gumbi.length; i++) {
            stevecC = 0;
            stetjeV[i] = "";
            for (int j = 1; j < Start.gumbi.length; j++) {
                if (gumb.getBackground() == Color.BLACK) {
                    stevecC += 1;
                } else if (gumb.getBackground() == Color.WHITE) {
                    stetjeV[i] += stevecC + " ";
                }
            }
            if (stevecC != 0) {
                stetjeV[i] += stevecC + " ";
            }

        }

        String[] stetjeS = new String[10];
        int stevecS = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < Start.gumbi.length; i++) {
             stevecS = 0;
            stetjeS[i] = "";
            for (int j = 0; j < Start.gumbi.length; j++) {
                if (gumb.getBackground() == Color.BLACK) {
                    stevecS += 1;
                } else if(gumb.getBackground() == Color.WHITE){
                    stetjeS[j] += stevecS+ " ";
                }
            }
            if (stevecS !=0) {
                stetjeS[i] += stevecS+ " ";
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < Start.gumbi.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < Start.gumbi.length; j++) {
                if (stetjeS[j]==stolpci[j] && stetjeV[i]==vrstice[i] ) {
                    System.out.println("je prav");
                }else{
                    System.out.println("ni prav");
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: We only know what you tell us, and so far unfortunately, that's not much. Your responsibility when asking questions is to try to make it as easy as possible for others to understand your problem, and that means putting more effort into asking your question than simply dumping code here. Please **explain** things so that we can understand them. Please go through the [tour], the [help] and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions.

Comment: For example: what exactly is this code supposed to be doing? What are the specific roles of each class? What is it doing correctly? What is it not doing that it should be doing? What is it doing that it shouldn't be doing? Are you getting error or exception messages? If so, can you post them? What steps have you taken to debug your problems and what were the results of these efforts? .... etc...

Comment: the listener 2 is supposed to be checking if the black fields in the game are equal to the solution of the game. When I press the button in the game it should print (syso) its correct or its not correct but when I press the button nothing happens.

Comment: 1) Where do you add the 2nd listener to any button? 2) If it's not added to any JButton, how is it supposed to do anything? 3) I am concerned with your having it extend Start as that looks dangerous and a possible misuse of inheritance.

Comment: 1) I added the listener and I get an error: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
 at Resitve.actionPerformed(Resitve.java:23) 2)  i extend start just to get my variables to the listener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Start:

```
 static JButton[][] gumbi = new JButton[11][11];
```

In Resitve

```
 String[] stetjeV = new String[10];

 for (int i = 1; i < Start.gumbi.length; i++) {
        stevecC = 0;
        stetjeV[i] = "";  // NPE! because 10 is less than 11
```

Maybe here too:

```
 String[] stetjeS = new String[10];
```

And also in Start there are arrays with 10 elements.

Comment: Thank you for the very precise and comprehensive information "errors coming".

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
 at Resitve.actionPerformed(Resitve.java:56)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
.......... and so on

Comment: Perhaps you have another array with 10 elements?